# Does it mean that if my mac supports virtualization (has VMX cpu flag) the virtual machine (that I will install on my mac) will support it (VMX) too?

Tags: virtual-machine, kvm

When creating a virtual machine with Ubuntu OS on it, I set in the characteristics of VM: VT-x/AMD-V, Nested Paging, PAE/NX, Paravirtualization KVM. 
But after creating the VM, I run it and check for the presence of KVM and get:

```
yana@yana-VirtualBox:~$ kvm-ok
INFO: Your CPU does not support KVM extensions
INFO: For more detailed results, you should run this as root
HINT:   sudo /usr/sbin/kvm-ok
yana@yana-VirtualBox:~$ sudo /usr/sbin/kvm-ok
[sudo] password for yana: 
INFO: Your CPU does not support KVM extensions
KVM acceleration can NOT be used
```

I'm confused about this.
It turns out that my Ubuntu on the VM does not support hardware virtualization? (P.S. some instruction says that I need it to run Minikube)

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Oracle VirtualBox, it depends on what CPU of your host system.

Nested virtualization is indeed supported in [VirtualBox](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E97728_01/F12469/html/nested-virt.html) but **only on hosts running AMD CPUs**, yet. Which means that if your host supports VT-x (vmx) then your guest hosts will support it too (if you enable it in VM options).

You can use VMware or QEMU/KVM instead, which supports Nested Virtualization.

Further reading:

- https://serverfault.com/a/761234/534533
- https://www.linux-kvm.org/page/Nested_Guests
- https://stafwag.github.io/blog/blog/2018/06/04/nested-virtualization-in-kvm/